Add the link for every item in the flatlist
I want to add the link for every item in the flatlist I want to see the item at the top when the user click on the link from outside the app. It should redirect that item on the top of the flatlist.
Example:- inshorts app link changes for every item scroll
Like in Inshorts app. How do I achieve that in react native using flatlist.
I tried using the react native flatlist but I am not sure how to achieve this kind of functionality.
I am using expo 50 SDK and expo file based routing for my project. I don't know how to add link to the particular items in the flatlist.
